# Upgrade to Rails 3.1.0 from rc6, asset precompile fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

After I upgrade to Rails 3.1.0 from Rails 3.1.0.rc6, I got some error messages when running `assets:precompile` task like this:

```
$ RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets rake assets:clean tmp:clear assets:precompile
rake aborted!
ie-spacer.gif isn't precompiled
  (in app/assets/stylesheets/jquery.gritter.css.scss)

Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I tried add `config.assets.precompile << 'ie-spacer.gif'` to `config/application.rb`, but it still fails.

The line in `jquery.gritter.css.scss` is:

```
background: asset_url('ie-spacer.gif', image);
```

and I tried:

```
background: asset_path('ie-spacer.gif', image);
background: image_url('ie-spacer.gif');
background: image_path('ie-spacer.gif');
```

all failed with `ie-spacer.gif isn't precompiled`.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You have to do

```
config.assets.compile = true
```

during the assets:precompile task.

Seems to be a bug in rails 3.1.

Comment: Indeed, it looks like a bug. This workaround worked for me, too.

Comment: I don't think it's a bug as a new rails application generated with rails 3.1.0 will have this configuration set up for you.

Comment: It is a bug in Rails 3.1. You can also upgrade to the rails 3-1-stable branch, which includes this fix: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/2768/files

Comment: What's the best way to **only** apply that setting during the assets:precompile task?

Comment: This command helped me with active_admin 0.5.1 on rails 3.2.11.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to use both

```
config.assets.compile = true
config.assets.digest  = true
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out this is due to

```
config.assets.compress = false
```

Which is wrong, if you are trying to compile with

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
```

It should indeed throw a better error though.