# Rails assets images in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, production, assets

I found some strange behavior of assets images

If I run unicorn in production mode at hosting - /assets/image.png - server give me blank image ie file exist, but size=0 . In same time at localhost I run in unicorn development mode - and all works fine, Then I run webrick at hosting - images are display fine. After that I run unicorn in production mode at localhost and images stops display, then I run unicorn in development images already doesn't work.

Rails 3.1.0.rc6, after that I update to rc8 at hosting but nothing happened

Maybe production mode build some cache, which remains forever?

Comment: Try to Rake assets:precompile

Comment: Could you add the following information: configuration of assets in development and production mode?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are different things that may go wrong, so here the ideas you have to check:

- There is a known error in Rails 3.1, that  the precompilation of assets does not work properly. See [Upgrade to Rails 3.1.0 from rc6, asset precompile fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7252872/upgrade-to-rails-3-1-0-from-rc6-asset-precompile-fails) for a question with a solution.
- I had problems with creating precompiled assets for production. The following worked for me (after fixing the error above):

  1. Ensure that your application is not running in production mode.
  2. Call `bundle exec rake assets:clean`. This will clean all resources hanging around.
  3. Call `bundle exec rake assets:precompile` afterwards. As a result, the directory `/public/assets` should be filled with assets with the hash appended (e.g. `icon_add-96985e087048a8c2e09405494509750d.gif` instead of `icon-add.gif`).
  4. Start your server in production mode.
- Depending on the browser I used, I had to refresh or even clear all caches. Especially Chrome was very nasty in caching resources that he should not cache.

I hope some of the ideas will help you find the source of your problem.